how to close an account
I deposited solana on marginfi and I was charged 0.016 solana for creating an account HXnCRyaNnitnL3Vrie2vHXm2RgCciBfp9inW4k11RG4y.
question! can I close this account and get this currency back?
and if so, how do I do it?
transaction address
24AdKtsXGQ5StcfMdyTfD7ph57mLvwrRpXssRcvvwtGbtpv4nTV9QjndSXcGFY8gYTfHqHH6FnxNEHHdQDdhCZi7

After going through the docs, there isn't an instruction to close the MarginfiAccount
The withdraw instruction doesn't close the account -> https://github.com/mrgnlabs/marginfi-v2/blob/063a5defd89840dd53c018c563d96d0fad9dd922/programs/marginfi/src/instructions/marginfi_account/withdraw.rs#L137
